# Can Gangajal purify the puja room and puja samagri?

Tags: scripture, worship, puja

How to purify Puja samagris/ ritual objects when touched by someone not ritually pure, like who touched meat, washed his hands with normal water and touched the ritual objects?

Comment: yes sprinkling with Gangajal will purify .. use Durva grass to sprinkle with or simply mango leaf

Comment: @Rickross And will it be ok to use the same puja samagris for worshiping again after purifying them with the gangajal ?

Comment: Yes after being sprinkled with Gangajal everything becomes pure so can be used.